# Live updating from a .txt file to PowerPoint textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Quick note: I have no background/experience with VBA so will need some explanation as to what is going on.

I've wrote a Python script to pull the latest XML data from an IoT sensor (temperature readings) and store it in a text file. I would know like to get this data displaying on a PowerPoint, but this data could change during the PowerPoint, and I would like the PowerPoint slide to be able to update, receiving changes to re-display an updated version of the data.

To summarise: Currently, I have a text file with the data that needs to be read and need a VBA script to read it and place it into a textbox with live updates.

This is what I have found so far:
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00124_Read_in_text_from_an_ascii_file-.htm

The above page shows a VBA script that opens a .txt file and reads it until the EOF. I am not certain how this script would output to a textbox though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following page on the same site (mine, incidentally) explains how you can populate an ActiveX text box with your text. ActiveX might be overkill relative to a simple PPT textbox shape, but it does offer the advantage of scrollbars if needed.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, could you link to the article you mentioned?

Comment: Sure:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00486_Add_a_text_box_with_scrollbars-_populate_it_with_text.htm  and on the page itself there's a link to the previous and next pages.